# Where not to use IDF?

Tags: information-retrieval, tf-idf

What are the cases where Inverse Document Frequency is not useful in information retrieval?

Answer (score 1):

You may not want to use IDF if in your system, you do not want to weigh rare terms more heavily than the frequently occurring terms. Moreover, computing idf is a costly operation. This is evident from the fact that in the most commonly used scoring scheme i.e lnc.ltc we do not compute the idf scores for terms occurring in the document.

Moreover, if your search engine only processes one word queries, using idf is useless as if will be the same for each document. Hope it helps